# library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to build on XCode but `ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion` error occurs. I could build `react-native run-ios`. That would work, but XCode could not build...

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-google-maps'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-maps'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga'
>   ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: On M1 chip, using Rossetta to run xcode worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71115807/4031108

Answer (score 64):

For me, I solved just opening the `MyAppName.xcworkspace` instead of `MyAppName.xcodeproj`, and then, building.

Comment: For me too... but why?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much it solved my issue. But it would be better if you shed some light on this fix.

Comment: As for why its probably because you're using cocoapods and the pods are only included in the workspace so do not get built when building from the xcodeproj.

Comment: For those new to React Native, like me, you can find *. xcworkspace at [project_name]/ios/*.xcworkspace — Open this in Xcode instead of *.xcodeproj (I spent half an hour confused about xcworkspace vs xcodeproj)

Comment: it is very odd ... i had save ios project in xcode and it always works fine.. but now i had to remove this project and add it again and it started to work ... anyway thx

Comment: This should be marked correct answer  @Shun Yamada

Comment: Side tip: if the workspace isn't loading properly or can't build, it's because you need to restart xcode.

Comment: Coooooool!!!! thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue a bit ago after upgrading to RN 0.59.

The solution that worked for me, was to delete the `ios/build` folder, and then do this:

```
cd ios

pod install
```

When I did that, I saw an error about `Folly`, and people were recommending to do this:

```
pod deintegrate

pod install
```

I did that, but it will still throwing the error about `Folly`, so I deleted the `Podfile.lock` because pods was holding onto an old version of Folly that was incompatible with RN 0.59.

NOTE: I found a post by someone that said deleting the entire lock file isn't recommended. Instead, you should delete only the relevant lines in the lock file, the lines that pertain to Folly. I had already deleted the lock file, but everything worked out ok.

I ran `pod update` which updated a bunch of stuff and completed successfully.

The next time I ran `pod install`, it produced a nice list of green, successful installs.

Then I did `react-native run-ios` again, and it worked for the first time in a while, except it produced the red screen of death.

So I deleted my app off the iOS simulator device, then ran:

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install

killall -9 node
```

The `killall -9 node` is just to kill the Metro Bundler. It is my favourite sweeping command for that. If you are running like twelve node.js APIs on your machine, maybe instead do something like `sudo lsof -i :8081` and find the process ID for Metro Bundler(s) and kill those by PID. For example if you see Metro Bundler is running as PID 27322, then do `kill -9 27322`.

Then I ran this in a standalone terminal:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

back in the VS Code integrated terminal:

```
react-native run-ios
```

IT WORKED !!!!!!!!

Then I ran:

```
react-native run-android
```

that worked but got stuck at 0% on the simulator device, so I deleted the APK off the simulator and ran `react-native run-android` again.

IT WORKED !!!!!!!!

Comment: Love the enthusiasm

Comment: it stopped working after I added another package and did `npm i`

Answer (score 7):

It happened to me when building the project on the terminal instead of on XCode, and it happened on both the CI and my laptop.

It happens becase you are building the project `app.xcodeproj` instead of the workspace `app.xcworkspace`.

So, you have to change the param in your call, from `-project app.xcodeproj` to `-workspace app.xcworkspace`. Note that also the param name changes, not only the value.

And now, a complete call example.

From:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration yourconfig -project app.xcodeproj -scheme yourscheme build -UseModernBuildSystem=YES CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic`

To:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration yourconfig -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme yourscheme build -UseModernBuildSystem=YES CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic`

Answer (score 5):

I just update Deployment Target to 11.4 from 10 and its worked

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything else for hours,
what worked was setting in my Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

The same as the `iOS Deployment Target Version` in `Info.plist`. They were different.

Answer (score 4):

After doing 3 days of my effort I found the below solutions.

1. Check you need to open MyAppName.xcworkspace instead of MyAppName.xcodeproj
2. Close the Xcode and try to Pod deintegrate and then Pod Install
3. Change build setting from Legacy to New build system.

For me, option 3 worked out.

Comment: "MyAppName.xcworkspace instead of MyAppName.xcodeproj" : you made my day !

Answer (score 3):

XCode can't find the lDoubleConversion library, you need to add the library to the cocoa pods file.

you can do this easily by following these steps

1.Add the library file to your podfile

```
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => './../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
```

2.Delete the Podfile.lock

3.Run pod install

4.Add the DoubleConversion.a in xcode Linked frameworks and libraries

5.Clean the project and build again.

That should works.

Comment: Where can I find DoubleConversion.a to add it?

Comment: not sure about the DoubleConversion.a, but DoubleConversion lib it's in node_modules/react-native/third-party

Answer (score 3):

Try to check if your project running well on a real ios device because in my case this error was only for builds on simulator because I've got mac with m1 pro chip.

To fix it you need to check "Build Settings" -> "Targets" -> "Architectures" -> "Excluded Architectures" and verify that arm64 NOT excluded from the project, if it excluded you should remove it for running simulator on m1 chip.
[image]

Comment: This answer should be at the top for Apple Silicon chips.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Remove use_frameworks! from ios/Podfile.

   ```
   target 'AwesomeProject' do
       # use_frameworks!
       ...
   end
   ```
2. Add DoubleConversion pod in ios/Podfile

   ```
   target 'AwesomeProject' do
       # use_frameworks!
       ...
       pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
   end
   ```
3. Clear pods.

   ```
   pod deintegrate

   pod rm Podfile.lock
   ```
4. Reinstall pods

   ```
   pod install --repo-update --verbose
   ```
5. Open AwesomeProject.xcworkspace and run your app.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: @RocBoronat Sure, it just means delete that file. Option '-r' won't be necessary as it is just a file, not a folder; you might require '-f' depending on the permissions on the file and for your user in the system.

Comment: Oh yap, I understand. But you wrote `pod rm Podfile.lock`. Maybe someone gets lost because of that.

Answer (score 2):

use platform :ios, '10.0' instead of platform :ios, '11.0' in Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit new to the iOS build process and I will share my solution to hopefully save anyone hours of frustration.

In my case, it was simply a stale/bad build. Make sure you opened the correct Xcode folder in Xcode `<YOUR_APP>.xcworkspace`, in the top menu of Xcode, select `Product -> Clean Build Folder`

Answer (score 1):

For me, I solved by adding the following code at the end of the **Podfile**

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
```

This solution will work for Apple mac M2 and macOS Ventura. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Fix for Apple Silicon M1+ chips:

`Podfile`

```rb
...

  post_install do |installer|

    # FIXES BUILD ON Apple Silicon M1+
    projects = installer.aggregate_targets
      .map{ |t| t.user_project }
      .uniq{ |p| p.path }

    # project.pbxproj
    projects.each do |project|
      project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      end

      project.save()
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      end
    end

    ...

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's as easy `pod install` inside `/ios` then close xcode and reopen it and rebuild. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I'd migrated to React Native 0.60 with cocoapods and I'd neglected to update my Fastlane build process to build using the `.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcproj` file.

I narrowed this down by observing that I could build and Archive build using Xcode but my Fastlane build failed. Noob.

Answer (score 0):

By activating `Find Implicit Dependencies` for scheme on xcode solved the problem on my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me:

Change the Deployment Target to 11.0,
Also change the AppNameTEST Deployment Target to 11.0

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install

pod update

pod install
```