# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in xcode 9

Tags: xcode, react-native

While building react-native project in Xcode following errors are accured,

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-no_deduplicate'
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/pradeepkrish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InnovaZones-bcvkbiqlzwpsqadbqmrlcqgqzvzz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/InnovaZones.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InnovaZones.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/InnovaZones_lto.o'
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: '2'
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/pradeepkrish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InnovaZones-bcvkbiqlzwpsqadbqmrlcqgqzvzz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/InnovaZones.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InnovaZones.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/InnovaZones_dependency_info.dat'

Comment: can you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

> command+shift+k

And

> command+alt+shift+k

commands in xcode and then build your app again. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.