# ld: warning: directory not found for option with rn0.60

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

When I try to compile the library folders cannot be found.
Occurs both via npm and xcode.

I initialised a new project with rn 0.60.0, added my Podfile and Deps. Also I added the workaround for Firebase via react-native.config.js

What I tried to fix was:

- Pod deintegrate / setup / install
- Delete node_modues / npm install
- Delete all caches, clean Xcode, delete DerivedData
- Check Library Search Path (is $(inherited))
- Remove/add Libraries
- Follow: [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option), [library not found for -lDoubleConversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion/55776414#55776414) ,
  [Error: ld: library not found for -lPods with CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods)

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'pasioapp' do
  # Pods for pasioapp
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'

  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Invites'

  #use_frameworks!


  use_native_modules!
end
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pasioapp",
  "version": "0.1.10",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "list": "eslint.",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "i": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "a": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.4.0",
    "@firebase/util": "^0.2.20",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "AsyncStorage": "^0.1.5",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "core-js": "3",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^6.2.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "hashmap": "^2.3.0",
    "npm": "^6.9.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-markdown-renderer": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.22.3",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-rss-parser": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-tag-input": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-testfairy": "^2.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Result:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDynamicLinks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAPIClientForREST'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCAsyncStorage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNDeviceInfo'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNKeychain'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-DevSupport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTActionSheet'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTWebSocket'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-fishhook'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeNavigation'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-webview'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/pasioapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pasioapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pasioapp normal x86_64
    Ld /Users/nerdy/Workspace/pasioRN60/pasioapp/ios/build/pasioapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/pasioapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pasioapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/pasioapp normal i386
(2 failures)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I'm having same problem

Answer (score -1):

Please check the supporting iOS SDK version with the firebase and set the minimum deployment target to that supporting version.