# React Native can not build and run by Xcode10

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

New react native project can `react-native run-ios` to run on device but can not run by xcode 10.

It gets the error when I build the project.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-DevSupport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTActionSheet'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTBlob'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTImage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTLinking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTSettings'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTText'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTVibration'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTWebSocket'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-cxxreact'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-fishhook'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsi'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-jsinspector'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/glog'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/viatick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSHelper-ehajbfildwyjzqgtszurmsvheorm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yoga'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
```

I need to add some native modules in ios but now I get the problem with building the project in xcode10.

As I know, the ios project uses cocoapods then I try deleting the podfile.lock and run `pod install` again but it did not work.

I also tried delete `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` again but still get problem.

I expect to build it and can run from xcode. Now it only can run by command `react-native run-ios`

Comment: refer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050167/11212074

Comment: refer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion?rq=1

I am interested in your fix. We have the same problem. But the reference i gave does not fix it for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have opened `"projName.workspace"` ,then select your project goto `"General" tab -> "prjtNameTests"` then select host application `"yourproject"`