# Problems after upgrading to Xcode 12:ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, architecture arm64

Tags: xcode12

I upgraded Xcode to Xcode 12, and build my project.
Firstly, it come out an error such as below:

> ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/Users/ethanli/Documents/Aspira/RA.com4iOS/RA.com4iOS/source/ReserveAmerica/ReserveAmerica4/External/Mapbox/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents' for architecture arm64

I wiped out this error by adding "arm64" to Excluded Architecture in Build Settings. Refer to
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656509

[configuration like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KDQm.png)

But... another error came out:

> error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/ethanli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReserveAmerica4-cgnruuknmgycgrbadguodtkwspmy/Build/Products/DEBUG-iphonesimulator/ReserveAmerica4.app/ReserveAmerica4' (in target 'ReserveAmerica4' from project 'ReserveAmerica4')

I went to the path in Finder, “ReserveAmerica4” really doesn't exist.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 24):

I resolved this error.

The root reason is that Xcode 12 does not allow build arm64 architecture for Simulator. We should set x86_64 for Simulator building.

1. Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "YES" in target Build Settings tab;
2. Set x86_64 for Simulator:
   [image]

For more answers: [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios)

Comment: Thank you Ethan! I've been trying to figure this out for many days now

Comment: This seems to work for the simulators. When I try to do an archive build for any iOS device, I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Craig1123 This error is about architecture, you can show your error to me.

Comment: I made a new post with my error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123206/xcode-12-problems-build-input-file-cannot-be-found-building-for-release-on

Comment: Those who are using xcode 12, this answer is life saver.

Comment: It also works in Xcode 13 Beta 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can fix it in flutter with this

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Comment: Great answer! This solved the problem in my Flutter project!

Comment: solve architecture problem, but cause another problem 'module xxx not found'. apple m1, xcode 13.1, flutter 2.5.3.

Comment: I will answer how to fix module not found error also :)

Answer (score 12):

I got same error at M1 Silicon.
But adding ***arm64 to Excluded + Build Active Architecture Only*** did not help because one library failed with: `For builds to run in the simulator, this should be set to "x64"` error.

Temporary solution that worked for me:

- in *Finder* right click on *Xcode* app;
- select **Get Info**;
- set checkmark **Open using Rosetta**;
- reopen *Xcode* / *clean* / *rebuild*;

[image: app info]

Answer (score 2):

1. Comment the pod files about Firebase (you may need to comment your program code also), pod file example:

[image]

2. Quit Xcode
3. pod install
4. Restart Xcode and build the project
5. Uncomment the pod files about Firebase
6. Quit Xcode
7. pod install again
8. Restart Xcode and build the project

Comment: Tried to both update the pod and delete and reinstall pod, but nothing worked. But this workaround worked perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of things like installing pods, I cloned the project again deleting the previous one, it worked for me.