# Build input file cannot be found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

CopySwiftLibs /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app (in target 'beeapp' from project 'beeapp')
cd /Users/macbookpro/Documents/react-native/VirtualMusic/ios
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
export SDKROOT=/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk
builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign - --scan-executable /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app/beeapp --scan-folder /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app/PlugIns --platform iphonesimulator --toolchain /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/beeapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeapp-cpbklzhsycxubxegrkeglncegmlr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeapp.app/beeapp' (in target 'beeapp' from project 'beeapp')

Comment: I came across the same issue when I upgraded to Xcode 12. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: and so today it ran on my device after restarting my system multiple times but failed on all my simulators strange.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: This post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993084/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-12ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking. Then it could install on xcode, but not the react native cli. I deleted my yarn.lock and ran yarn to update the cli according to https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli.