# The iOS 14 simulator does not start up

Tags: ios, react-native

**Error Code**

> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

**To be solved**

I want to start up an iOS simulator.

The actual device is iOS 14 and I upgraded Xcode in order to build the actual device.

As a result, the simulator doesn't work and I tried many things, but it didn't work, so I'd like to hear advice from someone who knows how to solve this problem or who has been in the same situation.

**My environment.**

- npm 6.14.7
- node 14.9.0
- react 16.12.0
- react-native 0.61.5

**What I tried**

- Remove iOS/build.
- Clear the pod cache.
- Check whether the port used by react-native is already in use.
- Quit the iOS simulator.
- Restart the PC.
- Build with Xcode (I couldn't).

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890239/529282

Answer (score 1):

TLDR - delete `yarn.lock` and run `yarn`.

I had this same issue when upgrading to Xcode 12. I first followed this post to make React Native compatible with Xcode 12 [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 12:ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993084/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-12ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking).

My project could then build with Xcode, but not the react-native cli. `react-native run-ios` threw the error
`Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`
Removing my yarn.lock file and running `yarn` did the trick as the new cli version has updates to this problem - https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1235.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: FYI: For those like me who find this post years after it originated, please note that it's now standard practice to decouple the cli from your app. This means that `@react-native-community/cli` is no longer part of my package.json.

I mention this because, although I run commands with `npx`, I still get this same error as noted in this post. Still haven't figured out why.