# Why can't I build to simulator on XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode12

This is a somewhat peculiar.

I think this is related to XCode 12, but I made some simultaneous project changes, so it may be that. It seems that I can meaningfully deploy the project to devices running ios 13 or ios 14 successfully, project runs fine, but when I try to deploy to the simulator, it can't copy some stuff into the target. I've looked at many related questions in various forums and haven't seen this addressed specifically.

```
    CopySwiftLibs /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.app (in target 'APPNAME' from project 'PROJNAME')
cd /Users/seanl/development/Projdir
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk
builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign - --scan-executable /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME --scan-folder /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/PlugIns --scan-folder /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework --scan-folder /Users/seanl/development/Projdir/Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework --scan-folder /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WhirlyGlobeMaplyComponent.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework --scan-folder /Users/seanl/development/Projdir/Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework --scan-folder /Users/seanl/development/Projdir/Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework --scan-folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework --platform iphonesimulator --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PROJNAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep
```

always results in:

```
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/seanl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJNAME-dmjlgigvatannqerrubxabptwsnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app/APPNAME' (in target 'APPNAME' from project 'PROJNAME')
```

As I said, this is only building to the simulator, device works fine. One interesting point is that it's not using swift, and yet there's a copySwiftLibs call , though maybe that's a generic library copy.

I've scoured the net for ideas, any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quit Xcode, throw away the DerivedData folder, restart the computer. Now does it work?

Comment: I've had this exact error for 5 days now. I've tried everything matt said and more to no avail. It is definitely an Xcode 12 problem though

Comment: Quit xcode, trashed derved data, cleaned the build folder - still the same result.

Comment: This post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993084/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-12ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking. Then it could install on xcode, but not the react native cli. I deleted my yarn.lock and ran yarn to update the cli according to https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli.