# "warning: directory not found; error: library not found" using Xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to build an iOS app using Xcode. I'm new to XCode.
I had trouble building it for release purposes with this command : `bundle exec fastlane beta` that lead to an error :

```
❌  ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
```

I didn't know what to do so I started by trying to build my app with Xcode, and had this stack :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-cameraroll'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-webview'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-eeuzlarvkxgtncfhtkicciemdrtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From what I already read, I should add these libraries to the **Search Paths > Library Search Paths** in XCode but these libraries already are set in this configuration. ( screenshot below )

[image: config1 screenshot]

And the "PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD" is set as below :

[image: config2 screenshot]

I tried removing those paths and launch the build again, but the project couldn't build. So I reverted the changes.
I'm not sure about what I need to do as I'm new to XCode and this is an existing project.

Comment: Already tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion but didn't solve my issue even though I had the exact same problem.

Comment: I solved this by closing XCode, and opening the workspace file when prompted by XCode. 
**File** > **Workspace Settings** > **Build System** select **New Build System** instead of _Legacy Build System_ .

I still did the steps here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562596/library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion so definitely check it out.